# str_replace a .TPL variable?

Tags: php, smarty, str-replace

I have a variable named {$user.login} that I use in a URL like this:

http://profiles.mysite.com/{$user.login}

I want to replace spaces with + symbols like this:

"User name" becomes "User+name".

This way, my links will be cleaner.

Instead of http://profiles.mysite.com/User%20name I would have http://profiles.mysite.com/User+name

Any way I can do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use the alternate method for URL encoding?  How do you do your URL encoding now?  In Smarty or PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) translates spaces into `+` signs.

Try:  `http://profiles.mysite.com/{$user.login|urlencode}` in your template.